# Constructing resultMap to create different instances for the same collection

Tags: java, mybatis

(Using MyBatis v3.0.4.) 
I have a problem that I do not know how to solve. My object model is:

Location.java

```
public class Location {
    // ... other content
    private List addresses; 
    // ... other content
}
```

Address.java

```
public class Address { 
    public enum Type { POSTAL, POBOX, INPUT, CLEANSED } 
    private Type type; 
    private String line1; 
    // ... other content
}
```

My SQL is:

```
SELECT 
    // ... other content 
    postal_address_line_1, 
    postal_address_line_2, 
    postal_address_city, 
    cleansed_address_line_1, 
    cleansed_address_line_2, 
    cleansed_address_city, 
    // ... other content
```

How would I construct a `resultMap` that would plug the appropriate 
columns into an address instance of the correct type and added to the 
same list in Location.java? I would like to avoid having to add 
another instance variable to Location.java just to hold a different 
type of address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along the lines of Andy Pryor's suggestion, I was able to solve the problem by updating my SQL statement to something like the following:

```
SELECT 
// ... other content 
'POSTAL' as Postal_Address_Type,
postal_address_line_1, 
postal_address_line_2, 
postal_address_city,
'CLEANSED' as Cleansed_Address_Type,
cleansed_address_line_1, 
cleansed_address_line_2, 
cleansed_address_city, 
// ... other content
```

Then update my `resultMap` to the following:

```
<resultMap ...>
    //... other content
    <association property="postalAddress" javaType="com.x.y.z.Address">
        <result property="type" column="Postal_Address_Type"/>
        <result property="line1" column="Address_Part_1_Name"/>
        <result property="line2" column="Address_Part_2_Name"/>
        //...other content
    </association>
    <association property="cleansedAddress" javaType="com.x.y.z.Address">
        <result property="type" column="Cleansed_Address_Type"/>
        <result property="line1" column="Address_Part_1_Name"/>
        <result property="line2" column="Address_Part_2_Name"/>
        //...other content
    </association>
</resultMap>
```

Finally, within my `Address` class I am able to have `setType(Type)` and the inbuilt enumerated type handler does the magic. Within the `Location` class I can just have one list of instances of `Address` and the various setXXXAddress() methods can add to this list appropriately.

It is unfortunate that I cannot plug the columns into some sort of factory class but putting hard-coded types into the SQL statement isn't too dirty, in my opinion. The disadvantage is that I have introduced coupling between the domain model's `Address.Type` values and the SQL statement but this is kind of already there given that the `resultMap` SQL XML needs to hold the names of instance variables in the `Address` class anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Use a discriminator tag in your result map.

Look at the [mybatis user guide](http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/downloads/detail?name=MyBatis-3-User-Guide.pdf).  Search for "discriminator" you see more informations.

```
<resultMap id="vehicleResult" type="Vehicle">
   <id property=”id” column="id" />
   <result property="sharedPropA" column="shared_column"/>
   <discriminator javaType="int" column="address_type">
     <case value="1" resultMap="postalResultMap"/>
     <case value="2" resultMap="inputResultMap"/>
     <case value="3" resultMap="cleanResultMap"/>
     <case value="4" resultMap="whatIsaCleansedAddressResultMap"/>
   </discriminator>
</resultMap>
```

**Addition 1:**

You need to select the addresses as different rows.

i.e

```
select
    postal_address_line_1 as line1, 
    postal_address_line_2 as line2, 
    postal_address_city as city,
    type as 'POSTAL'
```

....

union

```
select
    postal_address_line_1 as line1, 
    postal_address_line_2 as line2, 
    postal_address_city as city,
    type as 'CLEANSED'
```

.....

then the built in enum type handler should set the type correctly.

Comment: No, this is not quite what I am after. Following on from my example, I need to be able to create two instances of the same class, Address, for each given result set but set the type property of the Address instance appropriately. I do see the MyBatis ObjectFactory, too, but it does not expose the column names which would enable me to decide how to set the Address type.

Comment: Oh, well generally many to 1 relationships are stored in seperate tables.   But in this case, just do 2 selects, and union them.  Them the have a result map for the type field to set the enum type.